# webpack: SASS loader fails "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js)"

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, ecmascript-6, sass

I've been trying to use `sass-loader` on webpack v4, but it fails to load `scss` files in a `React` component with `TypeScript`.

Here is a simplified snippet of the code.

```
//index.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import './styles.scss';

const Navigation = () => {
    return (<div className="app-bar"></div>)
}


//styles.scss
.app-bar { 
    background-color: #2196f3;
}
```

The following code is from my webpack config.

```
module: {
    rules: [
    //loaders for jsx, tsx etc
    {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true
                }
            },
            { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
    }]
},
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
]
```

I followed [the official doc's example](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders#using-loaders), but it fails to load the `styles.scss`.

Just in case, I re-installed `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader` (and `node-sass`), but it didn't solve the error.

The error message is ...

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

I'm running webpack via `Laravel Mix`, but don't know if Laravel has anything to do with it.

What caused this issue? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to put css in the test section because the sass-loader and css-loader will take care for you and it will transform your scss to css file

Below is my config

```
{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    //'style-loader' was the culprit, so I just needed to remove it
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but unfortunately it didn't solve the error :(

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere so I can take a look

Comment: I just needed to remove `style-loader` from your suggestion!

Comment: Where is supposed to write that line? im using laravel-mix

Comment: Add to your webpack config

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having the same issues with webpack. I switched from SASS to Styled Components, it's a css-in-js library. I was wary at first but it's great.

https://www.styled-components.com/

It allows you to change CSS styles programmatically using React props. For example if I want to change the opacity of a menu when a button is clicked I can do it like this:

```
opacity: ${props => (props.menuOpen ? 1 : 0)};
```

That’s just one benefit, check the docs to see others. I find using React with styled-components is a great way to work. You have your JS, CSS and HTML all being generated in one place.

[image]